# how to fix a 404 error on a specific page after upgrading from Joomla 3.4.4 to 3.4.5

Tags: joomla, joomla3.4

This is my client's site http://laerskoolnewtonpark.co.za/

On the left hand side there is a link to a virtual tour (Virtuele Toer is just afrikaans, it's an afrikaans school) and when you click on it you get a 404 error. Now it was working before the upgrade from 3.4.4 to 3.4.5, but not anymore.

I am new to Joomla, I have 5 years experience with Wordpress though. The piece of content seems to be created or at least placed on the page using a module called Custom HTML, it does't seem like they are using another virtual tour plugin or module but as I am new to Joomla I can't be sure yet. I have also checked to see if there are plugins or modules that need updating but everything seems to be current.

Please help me get the virtual tour page linked and working again. thanks

Comment: Can you remember is the link identical before and after the upgrade? or at least, was the link point to internal page (Joomla! component) or external (custom) page?

Comment: Thanks for this @cwps. I did not check this page link before so I wouldn't know. This is the link it takes you to [link](http://laerskoolnewtonpark.co.za/virtuele-toer/flash/GreenRoom_Laarskool.html). Now I have looked but I can't find a page or article/item for this url, only the module called "Virtuele Toer" (in english Virtual Tour) created using the Custom HTML module. I also can't find any media, be it video or pictures for this virtual tour, which is what's so confusing. If the issue was just about a broken link I could fix that. I am guessing it might be an external page?

Comment: I just realized all your link is not using url rewriting (they all have /index.php/), but not the tour link. Maybe (just maybe) the 'virtuele-toer/flash/GreenRoom_Laarskool.html' file or the directory '/virtuele-toer' got deleted/renamed. You could check your backup if that file/path exist.

Comment: Yeah it is odd that it's different. Will check. Thanks @cwps

Comment: I have looked everywhere, and I can't find any folder or path like that

Comment: @cwps I am contacting the host to see if they can help